# Why cannot \cref command distinguish between two subfigures?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

[image]

My problem is that `cref` command does not reference figures according to the numbers assigned by `subfigures` environment. Here is the source code:

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}


\begin{subfigures}

    % Subfigure 1
    \begin{figure}

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 1}

        \label{fig1}
        \caption{Caption 1}

    \end{figure}


    % Subfigure 2
    \begin{figure}

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 2}

        \label{fig2}
        \caption{Caption 2}

    \end{figure}


\end{subfigures}


\centering Reference to Figure 1a typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig1}} 

\centering Reference to Figure 1b typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig2}}

\centering The referencing output should be something like this: \textbf{fig. 1a} and \textbf{fig. 1b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: labels should be placed *after* the caption.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `cleveref`:

> Cleveref doesn’t know about the subfloat package, so you have to revert
>   to using \ref for cross-references to sub-figures. (Might be fixed in a future
>   version.)

There has been no update since 2013, but you can do it yourself (note you can put the definition in a `cleveref.cfg` file):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \Crefname{subfigures}{figure}{figures}%
  \Crefname{subfigures}{Figure}{Figures}%


\begin{document}

\begin{subfigures}
    % Subfigure 1
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 1}
        \caption{Caption 1}\label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
    % Subfigure 2
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 2}
        \caption{Caption 2}\label{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\end{subfigures}
\centering Reference to Figure 1a typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig1}}
\centering Reference to Figure 1b typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig2}}.
\centering The referencing output should be something like this: \textbf{\ref{fig1}} and \textbf{\ref{fig2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

According to  the package author, the above quote either  refers (!) to referencing (!! – not clever) just the subfloat component (`a`, `b`), or is a relic of a previous version of the package.

Comment: `\cref{fig1}` produces the correct output for me, without that `\Crefname...`

Comment: @Troy: Works for me too. Strange. Or maybe I tested first the O.P.'s version of the code (label before caption) and I forgot to check whether it worked just coding in the right order. However, I don't understand why this warning in cleveref documentation.

Comment: Yes, it really works after moving the label to be after the caption, but combining normal figures labels with subfigures labels in the same `\cref` command still does not work, though. I think I will post another question about this issue

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for having corrected my writing stutter ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I think the warning in the cleveref documentation was about references to just the subfigure component ("a", "b" in the OP's example). Either that, or the warning is a relic from an older version, and obsolete :)

Comment: @TobyCubitt: Thanks for this information. I think I won't remove my answer, but add the information, as I think it may be useful  for beginners to show one can customise `cleverref`.